# Python2.7 chat using sockets and select module(non-blocking code)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sockets, select, networking

Hi i have an exercise to build with sockets select and msvcrt, server and clients of mltiplie chat(the server and the clients need to be built non-blocking) that every client will send message and the server will send the message to all the clients except the one who sent it, the server:

```py
import socket
import select


IP = "192.168.1.154"
port = 123
default_buffer_size = 1024
open_client_sockets = []
messages_to_send = []


def send_waiting_messages(wlist):

    for message in messages_to_send:
        (client_sock, data) = message
        if client_sock in wlist:
            for sock in open_client_sockets:
                if sock is not client_sock:
                    sock.send(data)
            messages_to_send.remove(message)


def main():

    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.bind((IP, port))
    sock.listen(5)
    print("The server is on and waiting for client...")
    while True:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select([sock] + open_client_sockets, open_client_sockets, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is sock:
                (new_socket, addr) = sock.accept()
                open_client_sockets.append(new_socket)
            else:
                data = current_socket.recv(default_buffer_size)
                if data == "":
                    open_client_sockets.remove(current_socket)
                    print("Connection with client closed")
                else:
                    messages_to_send.append((current_socket, 'Hello ' + data))
        send_waiting_messages(wlist)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Building the server wasnt hard because it was guided(if it was not guided i would never got this code working) by the book but i have problem building the client and the main reason is that i dont understand how `select.select` works, couldn't find answer that will simplify enough this module for me.
this is what i did with the client:

```py
import socket
import select
import msvcrt

IP = "192.168.1.154"
port = 123


sockets = []


def write():
    pass


def main():
    sock = socket.socket()
    sock.connect((IP, port))
    while True:
        rlist, wlist, xlist = select.select(sockets, sockets, [])
        for current_socket in rlist:
            if current_socket is sock:
                data = current_socket.recv(1024)
                print(data)
            else:
                sockets.append(current_socket)
        write()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This probably shows you that I have low understanding of the module select and the exercise actually. I saw some threads that has similar question but I understand nothing from them so I realy need good explantion.
In conclusion I realy am lost...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` takes as parameters a list of sockets to wait for readablity, a list of sockets to wait for writability, and a list of sockets to wait for errors.  It returns lists of ready to read, ready to write, and error sockets.  From help:

```
>>> help(select.select)
Help on built-in function select in module select:

select(...)
    select(rlist, wlist, xlist[, timeout]) -> (rlist, wlist, xlist)

    Wait until one or more file descriptors are ready for some kind of I/O.
    The first three arguments are sequences of file descriptors to be waited for:
    rlist -- wait until ready for reading
    wlist -- wait until ready for writing
    xlist -- wait for an ``exceptional condition''
    If only one kind of condition is required, pass [] for the other lists.
    A file descriptor is either a socket or file object, or a small integer
    gotten from a fileno() method call on one of those.

    The optional 4th argument specifies a timeout in seconds; it may be
    a floating point number to specify fractions of seconds.  If it is absent
    or None, the call will never time out.

    The return value is a tuple of three lists corresponding to the first three
    arguments; each contains the subset of the corresponding file descriptors
    that are ready.

    *** IMPORTANT NOTICE ***
    On Windows, only sockets are supported; on Unix, all file
    descriptors can be used.
```

So to fix your client, you need to add the socket you opened (`sock`) to the `sockets` list.  Your `write` function can then be called if your socket is ready to be written.

In `write`, use `msvcrt.kbhit()` to test for characters typed.  You can't just use `input` because it will block.  Then read the character if one has been typed.  Collect up the characters until you hit `enter`, then build a message and write it to the socket.  Something like:

```
message = []

def write(sock):
    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        c = msvcrt.getche()
        if c == '\r':
            data = ''.join(message)
            print 'sending:',data
            sock.sendall(data)
            message.clear()
        else:
            message.append(c)
```